# Getting a list and posting to pages in parent-child relationship using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, parent-child, publish

I've been trying to figure out how to retrieve a list of child pages for a given Facebook page. We have a customer that has a master page and several hundred child pages under it (set up by Facebook staff). When I create a page for a user (not in a parent-child relationship) then I can access /me/accounts to get the list and the page access token. But when I use the /me/accounts API on the customer's account I only see the parent page and none of the child pages.

1. How do I get a list of children for the parent page? I tried using
   /PARENT_PAGE_ID/accounts (pages, children, etc, etc) but none of
   them seem to exist - I couldn't find any mention on the FB developer
   page regarding how to do this
2. How do I post to the child pages using the graph API? The user I'm
       using has permissions to post on the child pages (on the Facebook
       page) and even though I'm logged in as the user, the posts show up
       as if they were posted by the page. When I try to post to
       /CHILD_PAGE_ID/feed using the user token (or even parent page token)
       I get a successful response from the API but don't see the post show
       up. When I publish to a regular page it works fine.
3. Is it always the case that when a user posts to a child page that
       the posts will always show up as posted by the page admin? For
       regular pages you have to "log in as page" to do this so this
       behavior seems different.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Parent/Child pages are not exposed directly from the Graph API.  Since the Parent/Child relationships were created by Facebook staff, maybe they might have an answer for you.  In all my time with the Facebook APIs over the last four years, I've not seen parent/child pages.

Comment: It's a feature that was added last year, I think.

Comment: Please post a link to the documentation on parent/child.  I can't seem to find anything

Comment: I couldn't find any developer docs. Here's a press release info: http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/07/11/parent-child-corporate-local-locations-pages-places/. The relationships were set up by Facebook staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the solution. The use of Page API is not required for posting to child pages. While Facebook does not list the child pages under /me/accounts, you can still access the auth token using one of two ways:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/CHILD_PAGE_ID?fields=access_token&method=GET&access_token=USER_TOKEN
```

Or using PHP:

```
$facebook->setAccessToken(USER_TOKEN);
$facebook->api('/CHILD_PAGE_ID?fields=access_token');
```

Both are really the same and will give you the same array containing the child page ID and the token to use to post on the page.

Answer (score 0):

From the press-release (http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/07/11/parent-child-corporate-local-locations-pages-places/)

> It appears that Facebook will also support
>   the parent-child structure in the Pages API.
>   Settings, apps, and content moderation will be able to be 
>   controlled programmatically, enabling corporations to 
>   push changes to many Pages at once.

We normal developers have no access Pages API.  It must be something specific for the partners.  So to answer your three questions

1. Become a Facebook partner to gain access to the Pages API and its documentation.
2. Same as #1
3. Read the documentation from #1 that that answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll inquire about it but I'm not sure if it's a possibiliy. I find it strange that you would not be able to post using the regular /PAGE_ID/feed API.

Comment: If you feel this is the answer, please be sure to accept this answer so the question doesn't show up on the unanswered list.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I'm trying to follow up to determine if there is no other way to post and if the Pages API is the API to use to publish to child pages. Will flag once I get a response.

Comment: Your response is what I said.  It's not publically documented because the API is for partners.

Comment: That is not entirely correct, the page API is open: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page - the Ads API and parent-child administration requires partnership agreement.

Comment: That is not a link to the **Page API**.  That is a link to the Page object of the **Graph API**.